# Criando Crud em Nodejs Erro no post

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const users ={
  nome: String,
  idade: Number,
  saldo: Number,
  aposta: ()=>{return dados}
};
const dados = {
  gama: String,
  investimento: Number,
  lucro: Number,
  totalRetorno: (investimento, lucro) =>{let total = investimento+lucro; return totalRetorno}
};
```

Estou tentando criar um usuario

```
server.post('/users', (require, response) => {
  const { name, idade, saldo, aposta, game, investimento, lucro} = require.body; 

  users.push(name, idade, saldo, aposta(game, investimento, lucro));

  console.log("Usuario criado")
  return response.json(users, dados);
});
```

Nao consigo criar o usuario nao sei pq.
**ERRO: TypeError: users.push is not a function**

Comment: Mas o que seria **users** pra vc estar dando `push`?

Comment: `.push()`é um método de Array, `users` é um objeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não ficou muito claro, acredito que você ao fazer o push não ta tratando os dados como objeto, se você colocasse desta forma :

```
   users.push({name, idade, saldo, aposta(game, investimento, lucro)});
```

poderia resolver esse problema.